# filter with clickable images (input) with php / mysql

Tags: php, mysql, notice

I have a number of small images (input type=image), which I want to use as a filter, e.g. if I click on the first image, in the mysql query I only want to SELECT those with the corresponding value.

It seems to work but I get a PHP notice. What am I missing?

This is what I've got so far. I enclosed screen shots of the MySql notice and table structure.

[image: mySQL notice]
[image: mySQL hats table structure]

```css
.thumbnails{height:60px;display:block;}.galery{height:200px;}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="image" name="panama" value="panama" alt="panama" src="http://static1.cuyana.com/media/catalog/product/cache/5/gallery/0dc2d03fe217f8c83829496872af24a0/5/_/5_hat_1_2.jpg" class="thumbnails">
<input type="image" name="tophat" value="tophat" alt="tophat" src="http://www.villagehatshop.com/photos/product/giant/3509260S41/-/size-7-1-4.jpg" class="thumbnails">
</form>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Melvin","") or die ("could not connect to server: " . mysqli_connect_error($con));
mysqli_select_db($con, "galerie") or die ("Could not connect to database: " . mysqli_error($con));
//$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats");
# neu ab hier

if($_POST['panama']) {
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats WHERE hat_cat='Panamas'"); 
} elseif($_POST['tophat']) {
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats WHERE hat_cat='Tophats'"); 
} else {
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats"); 
}

# ende neu
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
 
 echo "<img src=".$row['hat_name']." &nbsp; class='galery'>"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of 
if($_POST['panama']) { 
use if(isset($_POST['panama'])){
that should solve it

Comment: this did the job, thx a lot. :-) can you explain why this made the difference?

Comment: image input works like a submit button, therefore you can only post it if you click on it. If you do not click on it then it will not be posted and if($_POST['panama']) { will give an error, because the post variable does not exist, you welcome

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) so your code would become the following;

```
if(isset($_POST['panama'])) {
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats WHERE hat_cat='Panamas'"); 
} elseif(isset($_POST['tophat'])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats WHERE hat_cat='Tophats'"); 
} else {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM hats"); 
}
```

What is happening is that your code

```
$_POST['panama']
```

"Assumes" (if you will), that the array item "panama" is always going to be passed to the script, but this is not the case in your instance you either pass;

```
<input type="image" name="panama" value="panama"/>
<input type="image" name="tophat" value="tophat"/>
```

So using isset() will check to see if the item exists or not!